# Looking for datasets with daily inflation rate for as many countries as possible

Tags: inflation, fundamentals

Here's an example of the kind of thing I'm looking for https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/T10YIE

I'm also happy to perform transformation on other data to get an estimated/approximated daily value if anyone is acquainted with a good method to do so

Comment: If you actually want "daily inflation" - and not breaks - then look at the Billion Prices Project. http://www.thebillionpricesproject.com/datasets/

Answer (score 2):

These are breakeven curves, you should make it clear that you are looking for the forward expectation of inflation, not observed inflation (i.e. not the CPI indexes).

They are not normally published because they are derived from bond or swap prices which are typically proprietary to the relevant trading platform.

UK publishes breakevens for RPI (not CPI) here:
https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/yield-curves

Note, you also need to distinguish between curves derived from inflation swaps, and curves derived from inflation linked bonds.  They won't be identical.